# PHP Date difference

Tags: php, date, diff

i've the following code:

```
$dStart = new DateTime('2013-03-15');
$dEnd = new DateTime('2013-04-01');
$dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
echo $dDiff->days;
```

I don't know why i'm getting 6015 as result.

Comment: What happens if you offset the date by one? Try `2013-03-16` and `2013-04-02`, for example.

Comment: If i set 2013-03-16 and 2013-04-02 i get the same value 6015

Comment: I found de report of Bug#51184 https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51184

Comment: Obviously you can't right now, but as soon as you can you should put that as an answer and mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

Try like

```
$dStart = strtotime('2013-03-15');
$dEnd = strtotime('2013-04-01');
$dDiff = $dEnd - $dStart;
echo date('H:i:s',$dDiff);
```

or as per your code try with

```
$dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
$date->format('d',$dDiff);
echo $dDiff->days;
```

if you want diff in days try with this also

```
echo floor($dDiff/(60*60*24));
```

Comment: That is returning "01:01:00" i expect to get the difference in days between 2 dates

Comment: @GautamD3164 See comment on Haralan Dobrev's answer below. May be worth editing the answer for future readers

Comment: Hey can you tell me the reason to down it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this-

```
$dStart = new DateTime('2013-03-15');
$dEnd = new DateTime('2013-04-01');
$dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
echo $dDiff->format('%d days')
```

Check [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Please check [demo link](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7dq-mb7)

Comment: It returns +6015 days also it has to be a PHP version bug

Comment: @carlosduarte: updated post and added link for phpfiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7dq-mb7

Comment: In this example you add any date... Say change it to 2015 it is returning 17 days always

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 $datetime1 = date_create('2013-03-15');
 $datetime2 = date_create('2013-04-01');
 $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
 echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: It returns +6015 days could be an php bug? PHP Version 5.3.1

Comment: may be it returning error for your php version. I have tested and it returning +17 days.

Comment: I can't understand what's going with PHP, if i echo (1363305600 - 1364857200 ) / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ) it returns -A.9583333333333

Comment: Can you let me know which version of PHP you are using? Cause it's returns correct value i.e. -17.958333333333 in my local version & that should be.

Comment: @TapasPal: Please elaborate "my local version". What version? For me it still gives "+6015 days" on PHP 5.3.0. Check my solution how I got it through.

Comment: @Zeeshan, I am using PHP 5.2

Answer (score 1):

I prefer something like:

```
function days_diff($first_date, $second_date)
{
    $later = new DateTime($second_date);
    $then = new DateTime($first_date);
    return $later->diff($then)->format('a');
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the only solution that works at PHP Version 5.3.1

Comment: This won't work if the difference is more than 1 month. DateInterval will roll over and increment `m`, resetting `d` back to 0. Currently, you _must_ use `$interval->format('a')` to get the total number of days between two days (if you anticipate the range ever being above 1 month)

Comment: @ColinMorelli Thanks! I've applied the edit. I was using this function with no problem, but my case was always within a month.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same 6015 days on PHP 5.3.0 and found the solution using `var_dump()`.
My exact code is here:

```
$timestring = "Thu, 13 Jun 2013 14:05:59 GMT";
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y G:i:s T', $timeString);
$nowdate = new DateTime("now");
$interval = $date->diff($nowdate);
```

Now if I do a `var_dump($interval)`, the result is:

```
object(DateInterval)#5 (8) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["d"]=>
  int(0)
  ["h"]=>
  int(19)
  ["i"]=>
  int(45)
  ["s"]=>
  int(33)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  int(6015)
}
```

So the hours (`h`), minutes(`i`) and seconds (`s`) are set correctly but there is another property `days` which remains constant at 6015 and this is what others are getting as a bug. Well, I can't understand where it is getting this value. Again, as per the PHP manual for `DateInterval` at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php, I tried accessing them as properties of an object and things went absolutely fine.

Hence, I get exact result by:

```
echo (string) $interval->d." days ago";
```