# PHP strtotime date difference

Tags: php, date, difference, date-math

I want to get the age of users.
I tried:

```
$dStart = strtotime('1985-10-24');
    $dEnd   = strtotime('2014-07-30');
    $dDiff  = $dEnd - $dStart;
    echo date('Y',$dDiff);
```

But get 1998 instead 28, what would be the right code?

Comment: Think about what you're actually calculating with *timestamp - timestamp*. The result would be the number of seconds between the two dates which is itself, not a date

Comment: I got this code from a question here and it was marked as accepted. I knew that couldn't be right but I can't think of something else

Comment: I got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743882/php-date-difference ok that wasn't accepted but voted up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtotime()` is not made for date math. [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) is *much* better suited for this:

```
$dStart = new DateTime('1985-10-24');
$dEnd = new DateTime('2014-07-30');
$dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
echo $dDiff->y;
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/173055)

Comment: $d1 and $d2 != $dEnd and $dStart

Comment: Somehow my original text was in my clipboard instead of my eval.in code. Thanks for pointing that out as I didn;t notice it when I pasted it here.