# How to get startdate and enddate of the between

Tags: php

i have two value date
2019-07-30 as startdate and 2019-07-31 as enddate.
2019-07-30 more is date now.
and this my code :

```
$start_date = "2019-07-30";
$end_date = "2019-07-31";

$date_now = timetodate(DT_TIME, 3); //2019-07-30

if(($date_now >= $start_date) && ($date_now <= $end_date)){
    echo "promo active!";
}
```

and how i display promo active even though startdate 
bigger equal to date_now (30 >= 30)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP strtotime date difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026602/php-strtotime-date-difference)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
<?php

$start_date = "2019-07-29";
$end_date = "2019-07-31";

$date_now = date('Y-m-d');

if((strtotime($date_now) >= strtotime($start_date)) && (strtotime($date_now) <= strtotime($end_date))){
    echo "promo active!";
}
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/cX5ed

Note:- I have changed start date to `29` to show you how it will work. (as today is 29 july 2019)